# Vanilla JS Remove Array Element By Reference

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am aware that you can remove and element from javascript array in various ways like using Array.splice(), pop(), etc. or by its value.
Now I wonder, is it possible using vanilla js to remove an element of a javascript array by reference like you do in other programming language like c#?

example:

```
    var item = items.find(function(item) { return item.acreg === "abc-123";});
    //do some other things with item
    items.remove(item);
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript

You may find the index of element by reference using .indexOf() method

Comment: There should be a VanillaJS tag in SO :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.

Use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) with [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
var fruits = ["banana", "apple", "watermelon"];

// Remove "apple" only if indexOf found a matching element in the array
if ( fruits.indexOf("apple") > -1 ) {
    fruits.splice( fruits.indexOf("apple") , 1 )
}
```

This is overly simplified, but should get you in the right direction.